# Nodejs latest version on Linux Mint

Tags: javascript, linux, version, linux-mint

http://sideshowcoder.github.io/canned/ - requires me to have nodejs version 0.10.3

I have Linux Mint 17 which runs 0.10.25. Is the latest version of nodejs not available on Linux Mint?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of a strange versioning case as 0.10.25 is newer than 0.10.3, but 0.10.30 would be the newest of them all.

The latest version of Node is 0.10.33. Instructions for installing the latest version of Ubuntu 14.04 is [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) 'How To Install Using a PPA' header.

Comment: I didnt try it. Got away with 0.10.3.. but i approve this as the answer.

Comment: One thing they don't say, `sudo apt-get  update`; and then do the install.  Also, you might want to consider the "nvm" tool.  I don't need it myself but I am in love with `rbenv` ... Worth a mention, if you like that kind of thing.

Comment: Why strange? They're versions, not numbers, and dots, not decimal points. I would therefore expect 0.10 to have followed 0.9. Numbers never have more than one decimal point in them anyhow. ☺

Comment: To those that aren't used to looking at semver and other versioning, it can seem a bit counter-intuitive because most assume that `0.10.3` and 0.`0.30` would be the same thing. Also, simply doing an alphanumeric sort on those versions gives `0.10.25` as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

nodejs updates faster than the Debian/Ubuntu repositories can keep up with. Debian is renowned for sticking with working software versions to maintain stability.

nodejs.org provides simple instructions to install the latest versions using some very simple commands

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

Alternatively, for Node.js v7:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

Optional: install build tools
To compile and install native addons from npm you may also need to install build tools:

`sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`

This method will uninstall the nodejs-legacy package which was a symlink from node -> nodejs.